# scala: Adding attributes (odd and even rows) to xml table

Tags: xml, scala, scala-2.8, lift

In a Lift application, I’d like to add a special tag which takes the `<tbody>` part of the next table and adds `odd` and `even` classes (for example) to each `<tr>` tag. Alternating, of course. While I have found a way to add another attribute to all `<tr>` tags, there are still a few problems left (see code below).

First, it doesn’t work. `cycle.next` is called too often, so in the end, everything is an `odd` row. Other problems are that the code doesn’t exclude inner tables (so a nested `<tr>` would be transformed as well) and that it also affects the `<thead>` part of the table.

Ideas to make this code work? (Of course, if there already is a lift-based solution – without jQuery – for this, I’ll gratefully take it.)

```
// Helper class for looping
class Loop(val strs: String*) {
    val stream_iter = Stream.continually(strs.toStream).flatten.iterator
    def next = stream_iter.next
}

val cycle = new Loop("even", "odd")

val rr = new RewriteRule {
  override def transform(n: Node): Seq[Node] = n match {
    // match any Elem
    case elem : Elem => elem match {
        // If it’s a <tr> do some further processing
        case Elem(_, "tr", att @ _, _, _*) => 
            elem % Attribute(None, "class", Text(
                // add the attribute and concatenate with others
                List(att.get("class").getOrElse("").toString, cycle.next).reduceLeft(_+" "+_).trim
                ), Null) toSeq
        case other => other
    }
    case other => other
  }
}

val rt = new RuleTransformer(rr)

val code = <table>
  <thead><tr><td>Don’t</td><td>transform this</td></tr></thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="otherclass">
      <td>r1c1</td><td>r1c2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>r2c1</td><td>r2c2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>r3c1</td><td>r3c2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

println(rt(code))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with `RewriteRule`s seems to be that they nest too deeply. That is, once a rule for adding attributes to `<tr>` is started, it is not possible to stop it. (At least, it did not work for me.) However, I have found a recursive solution which works for me. Also, as long as there *is* a `<tbody>` inside, the recursion will stop early. If there isn’t, we might have a problem…

```
abstract class Loop {
    val stream_iter = Stream.continually(elems.toStream).flatten.iterator
    def next = stream_iter.next
    def elems: Seq[String]
}
class Cycle extends Loop { override def elems = List("odd", "even") }

// Call this when in <tbody>
def transformChildren(sn: Seq[Node]): Seq[Node] = {
    // Start a new cycle
    val cycle = new Cycle
    sn.map{ node => node match {
        case Elem(prefix, "tr", att, scope, ch @ _*) => 
            Elem(prefix, "tr", att, scope, ch:_*) % Attribute(None, "class", Text(
                List(att.get("class").getOrElse("").toString, cycle.next).reduceLeft(_+" "+_).trim
                ), Null)
        case other => other
        }
    }
}

// Look for first <tbody>, transform child tr elements and stop recursion
// If no <tbody> found, recurse
def recurse(sn: NodeSeq): NodeSeq = sn.map{ node =>
    node match {
        case Elem(prefix, "tbody", att, scope, ch @ _*)
            => Elem(prefix, "tbody", att, scope, transformChildren(ch):_*)
        case Elem(prefix, label, att, scope, ch @ _*)
            => Elem(prefix, label, att, scope, recurse(ch):_*)
        case other => other
    }
}

val code = <table>
  <thead><tr><td>Don’t</td><td>transform this</td></tr></thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="otherclass">
      <td>r1c1</td><td>r1c2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><table><tbody><tr><td>Neither this.</td></tr></tbody></table></td><td>r2c2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>r3c1</td><td>r3c2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

println(recurse(code))
```

Gives:

```
<table>
  <thead><tr><td>Don’t</td><td>transform this</td></tr></thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="otherclass odd">
      <td>r1c1</td><td>r1c2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="even">
      <td><table><tbody><tr><td>Neither this</td></tr></tbody></table></td><td>r2c2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="odd">
      <td>r3c1</td><td>r3c2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 different ways that I accomplish alternate table row classes:

1 - Use the jQuery [colorize plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Colorize)

2 - Use zipWithIndex when looping through your data to create the table:

```
doQuery.zipWithIndex.map{ case (log, i) => {  
    <tr class={if (i % 2 == 0) "even" else "odd"}>  
        <td>Data</td>  
    </tr>  
}
```

Comment: As I’ve said, I don’t want to use jQuery for this. Also, I don’t want to create indices on the server side because I think, odd/even rows are something the template designer needs to care about and not the programmer. (The programmer might create the template tag to do so, though.)